# Suggestions on DRY-ing this Out?

Tags: python, inheritance, dry, pytest

So I'm working on some code to help explore set theory. I am also testing this code with py.test, of which I'm still relatively inexperienced with (which is part of why I am using it).

So right now I am working on relations, and I have all these relations which subclass off of an abstract relation class (e.g. ReflexiveRelation, CommutativeRelation, TransitiveRelation, etc.). Many of these relations have similar tests, as demonstrated bellow. I would like to condense this so that I don't have to repeat the process each time I add a new relationship. I have already run into errors because of this sloppy arrangement.

I have thought about some different ways of doing this, but I'm not entirely sure if they would be cohesive with the py.test architecture. I was wondering if a more experienced py.test user might be able to provide with me some words of wisdom about this (or at least point me to the correct manual to read).

```
class TestRelation:
    __testing__ = "Relation"

    def test_abstactness(self):
        with pytest.raises(TypeError):
            relation.Relation(np.equal, '=')

class TestReflexiveRelation(TestRelation):
    def test_set_creation(self):
        with pytest.raises(relation.FalseRelationError) as fre:
            relation.ReflexiveSet(1)
        assert fre.value.message == "Relation must be a ReflexiveRelation"

    def test_subclassing(self):
        assert issubclass(relation.ReflexiveRelation, relation.Relation),\
            "ReflexiveRelation should be a subclass of Relation. It is not."

class TestCommutativeRelation:
    def test_set_creation(self):
        with pytest.raises(relation.FalseRelationError) as fre:
            relation.CommutativeSet(1)
        assert fre.value.message == "Relation must be a CommutativeRelation"

    def test_subclassing(self):
        assert issubclass(relation.CommutativeRelation, relation.Relation),\
            "ReflexiveRelation should be a subclass of Relation. It is not."
```

Comment: You might want to look into parametrized fixtures: https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html

Comment: Yes, this looks promising. I looked over it before, but apparently not closely enough. I'm posting the answer now (or what I think shall be the answer...we'll see).

Answer (score 2):

I think these parameterized fixtures are the answer. Thanks @jme!

```
 test_relations = [
        (relation.ReflexiveRelation, relation.ReflexiveSet),
        (relation.TransitiveRelation, relation.TransitiveSet),
        (relation.CommutativeRelation, relation.CommutativeSet)
    ]

    class TestRelation:
        __testing__ = "Relation"

        def test_abstactness(self):
            with pytest.raises(TypeError):
                relation.Relation(np.equal, '=')

        @pytest.mark.parametrize("ARelation, ASet", test_relations)
        def test_incorrect_set_creation(self, ARelation, ASet):
            with pytest.raises(relation.FalseRelationError) as fre: 
                ASet(1)
            assert fre.value.message == "Relation must be a " + ARelation.__name__
```